# Scanners only in Driver file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In Java, if I am interacting with multiple classes through a file called Driver, do I only need to import scanner in that Driver file or in all of the files?

Comment: Only the classes that *use* the Scanner object by declaring it or initializing it need the import. And actually no classes really need the import if you use its fully qualified name when declaring and initializing it. i.e., `java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you feel that you need Scanner to be imported?

Comment: I want user input to be used for functions in all of my classes, but I am only running the Driver class.

Comment: Ideally you should have only one class that manages input.

Answer (score 0):

Import java.util.Scanner into all files in which you want to refer to it as "Scanner", as Hovercraft said.